# What badges will be affected as part of the reputation recalculation?

Tags: support, reputation, badges

The [reputation recalculation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) increases the reputations of an upvote of a question from 5 to 10, matching the reputation of an upvote to that of an answer. This recalculation is being applied to the already existing questions, and 10 reputations is the standard value for a question upvote moving forward.

As part of this recalculation, which badges are reconsidered and awarded for the past activity?

From the [list of badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) these are the the one that depend on reputation total:

- **[Caucus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1973/caucus)**: Visit an election during any phase of an active election and have enough reputation to cast a vote
- **[Mortarboard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard)**: Earn at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day
- **[Epic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/145/epic)**:  Earn 200 daily reputation 50 times
- **[Legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary)**:  Earn 200 daily reputation 150 times
- **[Yearling](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling)**: Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation

The first and the last badges listed above would be easier to check for as elections happen only for a few days (caucaus), and for yearling only a total year reputation change is looked at.

However, the middle 3 are based on earning 200 reputations in one day, and so potentially all days in which a user's reputation had increased will have to be checked. These 3 badges are harder to check for.

As part of the recalculation, will all these badges (and others if I missed) be reconsidered? If not, which badges will be reconsidered?

Comment: Mortarboard, Epic, Legendary, and Yearling will all be doled out to those who would have earned it as part of the reputation recalculation. I am not sure about Caucus, but I doubt it. Note that badge assignment is done as a separate process, so may lag behind the rep recalculation.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the super quick response

Comment: Marked this as a duplicate because that's covered in the long wall of text in my announcement question. :-)

Comment: Yep, that's fine. The banner blog doesn't mention anything about the badges. Your announcement question (not sure why) has got a lot of downvotes so it doesn't show up on the homepage and when I searched for questions with the reputation tag I naturally skipped it.

Comment: Heavily downvoted because people disagree with the policy and don't think it should be implemented. Votes on Meta sites are commonly used as a simple way to indicate agreement or disagreement. You're right in this case, though, about the low score having the effect of pushing the post off the home page. It's been "featured" so that it appears in the yellow box in the sidebar on all pages. Anyway, no worries about missing it. Cheers!